# redbeanPHP чистый mysql запрос

Tags: php, mysql, redbeanphp

На моём бесплатном хостинге не работает та часть PedBean php что  отвечает за внесения и изменения данных, по этому эту часть хочу перевести на mysql запросы. 
нашёл вот такой пример но он ошибку выдает на уровне php ошибка в коде. 
Делал запросы без redbean они через раз работают тесть небольшое изменения в запросе и он нерабочий.

что за кавычки '`' это важно ?

R::exec("INSERT INTO 'users' ('login', 'password', 'name', 'familiya')  VALUES ('botemm', '123456789','Юрий','Писанка');",array());

Ошыбка при выполнении.

Comment: что такое в вашем коде `sql:` ?

Comment: Вот из стати пример https://obninsksite.ru/blog/php-scripts/lesson-redbeanphp

Comment: Уже понял что это ошыбка

Comment: Кавычки не те. Для обрамления имён полей используют обратные кавычки - бэктики `\``. Прямые кавычки `'` используют для обрамления литералов.

Comment: А как их вставит из клавиатуры

Comment: там где тильда `~`, слева от `1`.

Comment: Кавычки нужны только в случае, когда какой-то гений использовал в качестве имён/алиасов [зарезервированные слова](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html). В данном случае имена таблицы и полей вообще не требуется обрамлять кавычками. Хотя формально `password` и `name` входят в список зарезервированных, но текущий контекст в принципе не позволяет посчитать их иначе чем именами полей (впрочем, если обрамить, хуже не будет).

Comment: Перенесите комментарий с кавычками как ответ я отмечу как ответ.